# Jquery .attr() not working to update name of input field

Tags: php, jquery, html

Following is my html code where i am calling a function to delete the selected image which gets store in name property of input tag.

```
<input id="im1" type="file" name ="upimage1" onchange="readURL(this);" class="upload" required/>
            <span class="trash-area1" id="im1" onclick="readUR(this)"><img class="trash-box" src="img/trash.png" width="24px" height="24px"></span>
```

Following is my jquery code which gets a call on onclick function. its not letting me make name attribute empty of input tag.

```
function readUR(input) {    
            var id = $(input).attr('id');
            var ch = id.substr(id.length - 1);
            $('.trash-area'+ ch).css('display','none');
            $('#'+id).attr('src','img/plus.png');  
            $('#'+id).attr('name','');                      
    }
```

Comment: `readURL` or `readUR`?

Comment: try with .prop() instead of .attr()

Comment: Element `$('#'+id)` is the element clicked and it's not image!

Comment: these are seperate functions, both are working but in readUR function in the last line, its not letting me empty the input field name of id im1

Comment: .prop() is also not working

Comment: what's the relation to php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have same `ID` attribute on your elements. Rename one of them.

Here is modified code:

```
<input type="file" name="upimage1" onchange="readURL(this);" class="upload" required/>

<span class="trash-area">
    <img class="trash-box" src="img/trash.png" width="24px" height="24px">
</span>

<script>
    $('body').on('click', '.trash-area', function () {
        $(this).prev().attr('name', '');
    })
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rn78L9kh/

Comment: changed the id names, still not working

Comment: I changed code and attached jsfiddle

Comment: Thankyou so much, this answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('span[name]').removeAttr('name');
});
```

```css
span {
  background-color: tomato;
}

span[name] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span name="test">Can I haz name? Name exists -> Blue, otherwise red</span>

<button>Remove name</button>
```

Comment: sorry, irrelevant answer

Comment: I just showed you how to fully delete an attribute using removeAttr().

Comment: i know that, but i need to empty the name attr value.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `id` attributes from `span` & `input`
then , try the below:

```
function readUR(input) {    
            var id = $(input).attr('id');
            var ch = id.substr(id.length - 1);
            $('.trash-area'+ ch).css('display','none');
            $('#'+id+ " img").attr('src','img/plus.png');  
            $('#'+id+ " img").attr('name','');                      
    }
```

Comment: not working. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Correct code as follows...

```
<input id="im1" type="file" name ="upimage1" onchange="readURL(this);" class="upload" required/>
<span class="trash-area1" id="im1" onclick="readUR()">
    <img class="trash-box" src="img/trash.png" width="24px" height="24px">              
</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 function readUR() {
    var id = $('input').attr('id');
    var ch = id.substr(id.length - 1);
    $('.trash-area'+ ch).css('display','none');
    $('#'+id).attr('src','img/plus.png');  
    $('#'+id).attr('name','');
}
</script>
```

Comment: you did not understood the problem sir, readURL function is for another purpose, it takes url from input field and display it through jquery into and image, reaUR function is just to delete the name from the input attribute and display plus.png instead of original image.

Comment: Edited... Check Now

Answer (score 0):

First of all your jquery function is called readUR, but you are calling readUR**L**(this).  Fix this typo first.

Comment: Add the jquery script library reference below title in the <head> section: <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: rename the second tag with another id.  You should not have two tags with the same id.  Id's must be unique for every tag.

Comment: i have jquery and readUR and readURL are both different functions, i checked through console.log, right function is called on right click. i just need to empty the name field value of input tag.